# Convert String to Array Items

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, text

The below code create the file and puts the data in it but it saves as the following: 
`["123", "456", "", "789"]` How do I get a new `item` for each paragraph? the idea is the song lyrics would save to the file based on where the verses start and end. I am new to swift so there may be a better way to do this

```
@IBOutlet weak var songName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newLyrics: UITextView!
@IBAction func saveSong(_ sender: Any) {
    let sName = songName.text!
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = documentDirectory.appending("/Lyrics/\(sName).plist")
    let lyrics = newLyrics.text.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")
    print(lyrics)
    if let tDocumentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let filePath =  tDocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Lyrics")
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: filePath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                NSLog("Couldn't create document directory")
            }
        }
        NSLog("Document directory is \(filePath)")
    }

    if(!fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path)){
        print(path)

        var lyricArray = [String]()
        lyricArray.append("\(lyrics)")


            // any other key values


        let lyricData = NSArray(array: lyricArray)
        let answer = lyricData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
        print("File Created? \(answer)")

    } else {
        print("File Exists")
    }
```

I expect the output to be

`Item0 "123"
Item1 "456"`

actual output is

`Item0 ["123", "456", "", "789"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the *description* of an array to `lyricArray` with string interpolation (`\(...)`).
The description of an array is **one** literal string with format `"[\"item1\", \"item2\"]"`.

You have to append the *contents* of the array

Replace

```
lyricArray.append("\(lyrics)")
```

with

```
lyricArray.append(contentsOf: lyrics)
```

or drop `lyricArray` completely and simply write

```
let lyricData = NSArray(array: lyrics)
```

or – highly recommended –

```
do {
    let lyricData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: lyrics, format: .xml, options: 0)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Notes:

- Don't use `NSArray` to handle property lists in Swift. Use `PropertyListSerialization`.
- Never print meaningless literal strings in a `catch` clause like `Couldn't do that`. Print the `error`.
- And why do get the path to the documents folder twice with different API (okay, first the path and then the URL)?